# Adding new elements into DOM using JavaScript (appendChild)

Tags: javascript, dom

I sometimes need to add elements (such as a new link and image) to an existing HTML page, but I only have access to a small portion of the page far from where I need to insert elements.  I want to use DOM based JavaScript techniques, and I must avoid using document.write().

Thus far, I've been using something like this:

```
//  Create new image element
var newImg = document.createElement("img");
  newImg.src = "images/button.jpg";
  newImg.height = "50";
  newImg.width = "150";
  newImg.alt = "Click Me";
//  Create new link element
var newLink = document.createElement("a");
  newLink.href = "/dir/signup.html";
//  Append new image into new link
newLink.appendChild(newImg);
//  Append new link (with image) into its destination on the page
document.getElementById("newLinkDestination").appendChild(newLink);
```

Is there a more efficient way that I could use to accomplish the same thing?  It all seems necessary, but I'd like to know if there's a better way I could be doing this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a more efficient way, and seems to be using documentFragments if possible.
Check it out: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/ . Also this way should be less error prone and more maintainable than starting to mix up huge strings literals and setting them as innerHTML of some other DOM objects.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out for my next project.

Answer (score 6):

Just beware, that `innerHTML` is both non-standard and notoriously [buggy](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=innerHTML+bug).

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew `innerHTML` was buggy! Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with that. Using `innerHTML` would be marginally faster and probably fewer characters but not noticeable for something of this scale, and my personal preference is for the more standard, uniformly supported and safer DOM methods and properties.

One minor point: the `height` and `width` properties of `<img>` elements should be numbers rather than strings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about    height and    width.  That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adding many things, the way you've been doing it is ideal vs innerHTML. If you're doing it frequently though, you might just create a generic function/object that takes the pertinent information as parameters and does the dirty work. IE

```
function addImage(src,width,height,alt,appendElem,href) {...}
```

I do this often in my own projects using prototyping to save time.