# Javascript, DOM: appendChild and textContent

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I submitted a Firefox addon to the mozilla directory and it was rejected because of this:

```
item.innerHTML =   '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">'
                  + '<tr><td style="line-height: inherit; padding: 0pt; width: 100%;">'
                   + word.title
                   + '</td></tr>'
                    + '</table>';
```

I spoke to the editor and he tells me to "`use a text node and then insert it using appendChild, textContent, etc`"

That sounds like total gibberish to me, i have never used `TextContent, appendChild` etc and am a bit lost. Can you show me how to do the above and I'll edit the other 13 instances i have of something like the above in my script?

Thanks!

Comment: He rejected it, as it's possible to inject HTML code using this technique.

Comment: I know, thats what he told me... i know why he rejected it, but no idea how to use the other stuff he told me to use. Although this seems a bit helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962137/adding-new-elements-into-dom-using-javascript-appendchild

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to do something along these lines:

```
var t  = document.createElement("table"),
    tb = document.createElement("tbody"),
    tr = document.createElement("tr"),
    td = document.createElement("td");

    t.style.width = "100%";

    // note the reverse order of adding child        
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tb.appendChild(tr);
    t.appendChild(tb);

   // more code to populate table rows and cells
   item.appendChild(t);
```

**Note:** There are caveats to creating a table this way as things work differently between browsers. I would suggest consulting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_Javascript_and_DOM_Interfaces#Creating_New_Elements_with_the_document_object_and_the_createElement%28..%29_method) to be sure about FF.

Comment: Can you write a bit more of the code please? I have figured it out till the style property only. The other stuff as its on other lines... have little idea on how to proceed.

Comment: I updated my answer. Checkout the MDN link which has detailed examples.

Comment: What about the closing of the tags? And instead of t.style.wide cant I do t.style= "border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;";

Comment: @Ryan: document.createElement creates a complete element(closing tags included) where in your original you had to add closing tags because you were adding a html string to the dom rather than a dom element.

Comment: What about the other things in "Style" and where do I put the "word.title"?

Comment: @Ryan you using the above you would insert word.title to td. ie) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word.title));

Comment: @Ryan for border collapse it would be t.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse'

Comment: word.title contains stuff like a<b>pple</b> , how do I manage that?

Comment: `title` should be text, cannot have html in it.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to add the title and the html then?

Comment: for title, use `setAttribute("title", "myTitle")`. html is tricky as they don't allow `.innerHtml`. So you'd have to create all elements programmatically via `document.createElement`.

Answer (score 3):

He wants you to programmatically create the HTML in JavaScript.  Take a [read of this post](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/), it should clear things up for you.  Post a comment if you would like more information.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using innerHTML he wants you to use a function that changes the DOM in a more direct manner. AppendChild

> Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent
>   node. If the node already exists it is removed from current parent
>   node, then added to new parent node

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild. The format for it is:`var child = element.appendChild(child);`

In your instance i would do:

```
var newText = document.createTextNode(word.title);
locationInDom.appendChild(newText);
```

Where locationInDom is where you were going to use the innerHTML. If the innerHTML was going into a table then just add an id to the specific existing column and use the method getElementById and add at that point.

Comment: This is my exact code http://pastebin.com/L6hZHDLT  , in this file there are only two innerHTML thingies, can you please tell /give me the code to replace those two?

Comment: do you actually need a table there? Is it tabular data? If not just replace locationInDom with item and use item.appendChild(newText);

Comment: Its not my code so i dont want to make many changes, another dev, much more experienced than me did that, but he is sick and i have to make sure this passes approval or i am screwed...