# AJAX how to create a new element?

Tags: html, ajax, asp-classic

i've been using an online tutorial on how to use ajax to create a new element dependent on the users input. At the moment, all it will do is replace an already made div's innerhtml however I would like to create a new div and fill it with the input designated by the user. Here is my current code:

AJAX:

```
  <script>
     function showType(str)
     {
     if (str=="")
       {
       document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML="";
       return;
       }
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
     else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

         }
       }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","/ASPScripts/QuestionDesign.asp?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     }
  </script>
```

ASP

```
<%
 response.expires=-1
dim q
q=request.querystring("q")

response.write("<input type='" & q & "'/>")
 %>
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I'm aware its probably a very simple answer, i'm just very new to this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, what you are asking is how to append a new element to the DOM:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

newDiv.innherHtml = xmlhttp.responseText;

document.getElementById("newDivParent").appendChild(newDiv);
```

EDIT:  you can paste this code in console (f12 in chrome) right here on this page to see how it works:

```
 var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

 newDiv.setAttribute('style', 'position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; z-   index:10000000;     background-color:red;' )

 document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response however it doesnt seem to be working. I'm trying to append it to a div in a table and yet nothing is happening once the user selection has been made.

Comment: can you post your code in jsfiddle?   have you tried the code I gave you, outside of the ajax call, just a test?  try just appending a new element to the dom as a start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962137/adding-new-elements-into-dom-using-javascript-appendchild

Comment: see edit. I added a working example that you can run in console

Comment: Thankyou very much, I adapted it for my use and it works perfectly! thankyou!